# Kendo MVVM Value Binding not displaying value

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I have the following partial view:

```
<div id="config">
    Call:<input data-bind="value: systemCall" /> 
</div>
```

and the following view model:

```
(function () {

  SC.ViewModels.SystemConfig = new function () {

    // self reference
    var self = this;

    self.ViewModel = kendo.observable({
        systemCall: "System Call",

    });

    kendo.bind($("#config"), self.ViewModel);
  };


})();
```

I want to verify that this is set up correctly, so if I give systemCall a value of "SystemCall", shouldn't I be able to see this when I load the page? At present, I see nothing in the text box.

Comment: What is `SC`? What do you do with it? As fas as I can see in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/rMFZS/1/ it works perfectly.

Comment: I use SC as a namespace.

Comment: Are you forgetting to actually call `SC.ViewModels.SystemConfig()`, like in @OnaBai's fiddle?

Comment: No. SystemConfig is an IFFE, and immediately invoked function expression.